# How to fetch JSON subcategories?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from a local JSON file, here is the JS script so far

```
let accordion=document.querySelector('#accordion');
fetch('countries.json')
.then(function(response){
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data){
    let continents=Object.keys(data);
    for(let i=0;i<continents.length;i++){
        let continent=continents[i];
        let heading=document.createElement('h3');
        heading.textContent=continent;
        accordion.appendChild(heading);
        let countries=data[continent];
        let ul=document.createElement('ul');
        for(let j=0;j<countries.length;j++){
            let country=countries[j];
            let li=document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent=country;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        accordion.appendChild(ul);
    }
})
```

What it does is it shows the header of the data "continents" and the number of rows just fine, but whatever inside the array (which all of the content really) shows up as [Object Object], so I need to fetch this data properly and also the data inside the array objects.

Comment: Something like `li.textContent = country.name`

Comment: FYI these loops would be easier to write using `forEach()`.

Comment: If you need more detailed assistance, you need to post a sample of the data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple solution...
as referred by Bammar, I mislabeled my data

> Something like li.textContent = country.name

BTW country turned out to callback continents actually, so that's fixed and by forEach loops, I'll be fetching country data.